# Handling exception logging in a Java task scheduler program?

Tags: java, exception, scheduled-tasks

I need to design a Task Scheduler  Where

1) User should be able to schedule multiple task at the same time.

2) There should be proper error handling on  failure
 of any task and should not affect the other running tasks.

I found the related programme at  http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/CertainAndRepeatTime.shtml

My concern is about handling of point 2 in program provided at
above link. Say I schedule a recurring mail send process in above
 program which will be run first time on 12 september 2011 at 2 am, and will be repeated after every 2 hours  Say a one process  fais
at  8 am. I want to log it in log file  with task name and time details.
Now if I look at above programme i.e CertainAndRepeatTime.java. This program
will exit once it schedules all the tasks. Where and how should handle the logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/overview/features).

Comment: Thanks Thomas for pointing to Quartz. Could you give me some pointers how we can handle the logging in core progrmme because my prject allows me to use only standard java library.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Quartz, as Thomas Jung already said.  Check out [Citrine](http://code.google.com/p/citrine-scheduler/), a web management layer on top of Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle it like every other thread. Some try-catch-logging in the run method of the TimerTask.